# How do I declare an img width and height if my images are random?

Tags: html, css, image

Google page speed and other testing sites are telling me I should be adding `<img height width />` to all of my images.

If my images are random how do I dynamically add an images height and width?

for instance I'm looping through, displaying, some post attachments and they all have various image heights but all have a width of 200px.

So I can define a width, but not a height.

Edit: I'm using PHP

Comment: Images that have random heights? Um that's not possible

Comment: @thelolcat He means he has multiple images with different sizes.

Comment: @thelolcat okay, let me rephrase, the images are not uniform in height.

Comment: How are you looping through the images? If you're using JS or PHP, just include a function to fetch the dimensions of each image and apply that.

Comment: so whats stopping you to get the image height and put it in the html?

Comment: @thelolcat my programming knowledge?

Comment: ah ok but then u should tell us what language are you trying to learn

Comment: @thelolcat yes, I did forget to mention that, and I was more interest in the methods other people are doing it, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looping your images with php? if so, take a look at this:

```
<?php
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("img/flag.jpg");
echo "<img src=\"img/flag.jpg\" height=\"$height\" width=\"$width\" $attr alt=\"getimagesize() example\" />";
?>
```

More info here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: ah, this looks like the ticker. Thanks. I'll stick it in and see how it goes.

Comment: inb4 that's what she said.

Comment: @UzumakiDev Though it can work, if it are remote images and it has to be done on every request it can take ages to load a page. I'm sure neglecting to mention `height=` will be faster :P

Comment: @Marcel point taken, these images aren't remote though, fortunately :)

Answer (score 2):

Define width only, height will be automatically matched the content's height

Comment: I know it's not the be all and end all, but will not declaring height affect my page speed score?

Comment: @UzumakiDev not at all

Answer (score 1):

How are you loading your images¿? well you may use variables right, so you need to use a simple aritmetic operation, like this:

new_height =  height/width * 200;

For example, if you have an image that is width = 500px and height = 300px, the new height must be:

new_height = 300 / 500 * 200;
new_height = 120;

Answer (score 1):

css method:

```
img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

html method:

```
<img src="http://yoursite.com/image.jpg" width="200px" />
```

Just don't define the height and the height will automatically adjust based on the width of 200px and the aspect ratio of the image.